# Digital Signatures and preventing hacking

Tags: java

I have developed a system using Digital Signatures

The program is written in **Java**

- Provider = "BC"
- SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = "SHA256withRSA"

**Keys**

- The Client holds the public key
- The Server holds the private key

**License Generation**

- Clients request a license from the server
- Server decides if they should get a licenses
- Creates a signed object and sends it back to the client

I am wondering about easy ways to hack a system like this and what I can do to prevent it.

How can I prevent a user from decompiling my code and inserting their own code? (I am aware of proguard but hear that it can be worked around).  I am also a little worried about a user creating a false licensing server and somehow modifying the source code to point to their server (because I will be releasing the licensing and server code to the public).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- How can I prevent a user from decompiling my code and inserting their own code?

The short answer is that you can't. You can make it harder (e.g. obfuscation) but you simply cannot prevent it. The fact that most computer games are cracked within days of release is evidence of this.

Turning to the rest of your question: the design looks fine. It's hard to prevent a fake licensing server, but maybe it's not going to be a likely attack anyway. The attacker could just remove the license check from the client instead.

As @Yuval points out, rolling your own crypto is a Bad Idea, but you seem to be doing it the right way by using BouncyCastle. Just make sure you always "sign what you mean", that is sign the license itself rather than, say, encrypting the license and signing the encrypted version.

BouncyCastle's lightweight API provides tools for signing arbitrary blobs of data; I'd recommend you use that rather than Java's cumbersome "provider" interface.

You should also take care to ensure the physical security of the private key. If that gets compromised then you're in real trouble. It may be worth thinking about a mechanism for revoking compromised licences and replacing them with new ones.

Comment: I would add to that one comment, as I agree with Cameron. Since you cannot prevent anyone from decompiling your code, perhaps you can isolate a small subset of the programs essential data and serve it only to authorized users. The data it cannot be possible to mock nor generated that bit of information and have to be updated frequently, which is obvious. However this can make your clients extremely upset if they work in closed down network or something goes wrong.

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with cryptography and security - if it's of any real importance to you - never use anything home-made.

**Always** use a proper library.

The margin for bugs and mistakes in this field are huge. Your applications security deserves better.